# smtp gmail server php mailer not working

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I know this question has been asked many a times before. But the solutions didn't seem to help me . So hereby I am posting my code:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug=1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
$mail->Port=465;  
$mail->Username ="me@gmail.com";
$mail->Password="mypassword";
$mail->AddAddress("to@yahoo.co.in");
$mail->SetFrom("me@gmail.com", "myname");
$mail->AddReplyTo("someone@gmail.com","someone");
$mail->Subject="Greetings from ME";
$mail->Body="Greeting !! I am glad you received this message";
$mail->WordWrap=50;
if($mail->send())
{
echo "Mail sent successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Sorry mail could not be sent because of error ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

The SMTP Debug is:

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO messengerclick.byethost3.com 2015-07-26 12:49:42 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2015-07-26 12:49:42    
CLIENT -> SERVER: Y2hlcm9ja3oxOUBnbWFpbC5jb20= 2015-07-26 12:49:42  
CLIENT -> SERVER: Y2hldGFucm9ja3MxOQ== 2015-07-26 12:49:43  
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 sc16sm22415466wjb.28 - gsmtp 2015-07-26 12:49:43 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2015-07-26 12:49:43 
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-07-26 12:49:43  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Sorry mail could not be sent because of error SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I have enabled access for unknown apps on my gmail account.
I have also clicked on continue on this link
http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
after signing in.
I am running this from my byethost account. It is working fine for smtp.mail.yahoo.com

Please help me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you read the link in the error message? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: yes I did .. Made those mentioned changes to my gmail account after that only

Comment: You could give [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) a try using the xoath branch in PHPMailer - we need more testers.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re sure your password is correct, you can try these troubleshooting tips:

> - If you've turned on 2-Step Verification for your account, you might need to enter an App password.
> - Sign in to your account from the web version of Gmail at https://mail.google.com. Afterwards try accessing your messages in
>     your mail app again.
> - If you're still having problems, visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with
>     your Gmail username and password. If necessary, enter the letters in
>     the distorted picture.
> - Your mail app might not support the latest security standards. Learn how to allow less secure apps access to your account.
> - Make sure your mail app isn't set to check for new email too frequently. If your mail app checks for new messages more than once
>     every 10 minutes, the app’s access to your account could be blocked.
> - Try changing your password according to our tips on creating a strong password.

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754).

[Here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps), you can allow less secure apps. Click on Turn On to allow less secure apps having your username and password.

Comment: I have also received feedback mail from gmail about the same

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing similar issue
Try this out:

If you had your password last modified before 2014 change your password to stronger one.

It worked for me